# Que genera el error RPC_E_SERVERFAULT y como arreglarlo?

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection

Realice un desarrollo que usa el SDK del ERP Exact MAX, esta aplicación a estado funcionando bien por mucho tiempo y el entorno en el que esta ejecutándose no a tenido cambios, la cadena de conexión, usuario y contraseña etc etc.

De pronto la aplicacion comenzo a tener problemas con la inicializacion, momento en el que se conecta con el servidor y arroja una excepcion no propia del sdk

```
(Excepción de HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))
```

Sospeche sobre que el equipo que ejecutaba la aplicación dejo de alcanzar al servidor SQL, pero si responde a un ping.
Quizá las credenciales habían caducado o cambiado, pero entre con SSMS con los mismos datos.
Quizá necesitaba permisos de administrador  y así ejecute la aplicación pero seguía teniendo la misma excepción.

Tienen idea  de que significa este error, que lo genera y alguna sugerencia para solucionarlo?

el fragmento de codigo donde recibo esta excepcion es el siguiente:

```
string gsPrimaryConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=sqloledb;Data Source={0};database=EXACTMAX;UID={1};Pwd={2};", maxConfig.Server, maxConfig.User, maxConfig.Password);
                    try
                    {
                        objMaxUpdateWrapper = new MaxUpdateXML.XMLWrapper();
                        objMaxUpdateWrapper.Initialize(gsPrimaryConnectionString, maxConfig.Company, maxConfig.License, Environment.CurrentDirectory, true);
                        LlenaLog("Wrapper Inicializado");
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        return new UpdateMaxResult()
                        {
                            Success = false
                        };
                    }
```

Comment: No conozco ExactMAX, pero normalmente SERVERFAULT significa "algo malo ha ocurrido en el servidor, *busca en el log del servidor el mensaje detallado para saber cuál es el fallo*." Lo primero sería ver los logs del servidor para obtener más información. En general, los SERVERFAULT no se corresponden (o no deberían) con problemas con lo que envía el cliente.

Comment: Intenta utilizando el FQDN dentro de tu cadena de conexion!!! :D

Comment: Deberias asignarle una variable a Exception y poder ver esa variable bien la pila de llamadas y el texto de la excepcion.

Comment: **Demasiado importante** revisar https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1141/es-legal-tener-mas-de-una-cuenta-en-stack-overflow-y-pasarse-reputaci%c3%b3n-entre-e @AlfonsoCorrea te sugerimos agregar una respuesta de acuerdo a el documento [answer], sauldos.